# Is there support for .editorconfig in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, editorconfig

I open Visual Studio 2022 and create a new empty solution.

I add an `.editorconfig` file containing:

```
root = true

[*]
end_of_line = lf
indent_style = space
indent_size = 3
tab_width = 3
```

I add a new C# Web App Project to the solution.

Not one single file is correctly formatted. All are indented four spaces with `crlf` newline.

The *editorconfig* extension doesn't seem to have been upgraded to support Visual Studio 2022 yet. Is there a way to get editorconfig support in Visual Studio 2022?

Comment: It may be that declaring a `[*]` filter doesn't work. Try `[*.cs]` instead.

Answer (score 7):

The editor in Visual Studio does support .editorconfig natively, although in many cases it's up to the language implementation to apply those settings when editing.  If you open a document and then do *Format Document*, it should respect your settings (assuming the language you're editing will make those adjustments; different language implementations may behave differently, like maybe presuming the existing whitespace was deliberate and so not changing it).

Also consider sending feedback through Visual Studio requesting this feature.  The real issue here is that the template system that runs when you create a new project or a new file takes the file template contents and doesn't perform formatting on them after they're created (there are a couple exceptions to this, but they're not standard behavior).  Ideally, the template engine would format each document it creates so that the files all match the formatting rules that were already in place.

Comment: See also [the VS documentation for editorconfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2022) which mentions: "When you add an EditorConfig file to your project in Visual Studio, new lines of code are formatted based on the EditorConfig settings. The formatting of existing code isn't changed unless you run one of the following commands: Code Cleanup, Format Document"